# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 -> Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

Will users of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 be automatically upgraded to regular Ubuntu 17.10 when it's released?

Asking in light of all the recent news (discontinuing Ubuntu GNOME flavor, GNOME as default desktop in 17.10 & future releases).

Comment: No upgrades are not automatic. I HIGHLY ADVISE you read ALL the release notes first and strongly suggest testing a live 17.10 flash drive and fresh install due to the number of changes 17.10 brings. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.04

Answer (score 23):

Yes and No. No, this requires a specific 'yes I want to do the upgrade'. But yes, if you perform the upgrade, you will be upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10. There will be *no* Ubuntu-Gnome 17.10. See [this blog post](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/). If you are already using Ubuntu-Gnome 17.04, there are several guides about how to do this, and the basics are:

1. Disable/remove all third party repositories.
2. Run: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. Reboot.
4. Run: `sudo do-release-upgrade`
5. Reinstall any needed third party repositories.

EDIT: removed -d after do-release-upgrade

Comment: I believe the question was about what happens when doing what you describe here, as there will (probably?) not be a Ubuntu-Gnome 17.10 to upgrade to. I am just as curious myself! :)

Comment: It will be interesting, as gnome becomes the default desktop.  Perhaps Ubuntu-Gnome disappears? Currently in the daily builds at [http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/20170701/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/20170701/) there is both Ubuntu, and Ubuntu-Gnome

Comment: So people are fully informed, the -d option upgrades Ubuntu to the latest devel-release (if possible). You might not want to do that if system stability matters to you.

Comment: Just for your information: The upgrade process will disable third party repositories, but yeah, it doesn’t really hurt to be proactive.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the main issue. There will be no "ubuntu-gnome 17.10", so will `do-release-upgrade` upgrade to ubuntu 17.10? (with the ubuntu styling: a dock etc) will it upgrade to something that looks like ubuntu-gnome (ie a fairly vanilla gnome experience) or will it fail (since there is no 17.10)?

Comment: @JamesK As far as I can tell, there *is* an Ubuntu-Gnome 17.10, but apparently it is identical to Ubuntu in 17.10 - the current available downloads for [Ubuntu-Gnome are here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/current/)

Comment: I would like to think the Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome flavours will be different. Mainly because Ubuntu is providing a modified version of Gnome in it's main release.  The Ubuntu Gnome flavour uses vanilla Gnome which I would prefer (and currently using).

Comment: Just to add, I've  just successfully "upgraded" using "update-manager -d" this upgraded me to the latest beta/test version of Ubuntu 17.10 and still uses the vanilla gnome experience.

Comment: I HIGHLY ADVISE you read ALL the release notes first and strongly suggest testing a live 17.10 flash drive and fresh install due to the number of changes 17.10 brings. 
 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.04

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THIS ANSWER AND IT NO LONGER MENTIONS UBUNTU-GNOME 17.10

Comment: What packages will be upgraded / removed ? I have highly customized system (I use `i3gaps` as WM) and don't want my packages to be removed - only upgraded.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I don't think packages would be removed.  I would strongly encourage you to test your setup in a VM prior to doing an upgrade, however.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I did the upgrade yesterday and during the process there is an information that packages will be adder / upgraded and removed. But there is an option to review what will be done. At some point user is presented with option to see more details by pressing the `d` key. I strongly recommend anyone to write the output of this command to a file - it will be easier to re-add removed apps.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers on this thread are very old and were written based on outdated information. We now know thanks to [a blog post](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/) on the Ubuntu GNOME blog that after 17.04 there will no longer be two separate Ubuntu flavors.

According to that post:

> Next year, if you are using either Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS, you will be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. For normal release users, this upgrade should happen with the release of 17.10.

Meaning that users of both Ubuntu and Ubuntu GNOME will be placed into the same upgrade path.

Comment: @tonygil Of vanilla Ubuntu yes, not of Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: apologies, comment removed.

Answer (score 1):

Unity will be discontinued, gnome will be the default desktop in 17.10 and on. [Announcement from Canonical](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/). And just as Charles said, updates will be like normal, with user input required.

Comment: Re-reading the question, I may have mis-understood!

Comment: @CharlesGreen you were right on track, just a few facts of the question were a little off :)