# upgrading from 16.04lts to 17.1

Tags: upgrade

when I run the command "sudo do-release-upgrade -d" I get the error or the output 
"Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release."
please help!

Comment: With all the changes to Ubuntu I highly advise a fresh install rather than upgrading. Otherwise you have to upgrade from 16.04 -> 16.10 -> 17.04 -> then 17.10. 16.10 is beyond end of life and upgrading to 16.10 is no longer supported.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/10/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10

Answer (score 0):

This post looks helpful for doing the upgrade, but I agree with bodhi.zazen about starting fresh: [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 -> Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909323/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-ubuntu-17-10-upgrade)

Quick overview:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
-- REBOOT --
sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: Yes, but the OP is on 16.04, so they need to upgrade to 16.10 and 17.04 first.