# How to update from Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, repository

I'm trying to update from Ubuntu 17.04 and it is saying the following:

```
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu stable Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu unstable Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jessie Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cloud-sdk-zesty Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu apt/stable/ Release' does not have a Release file.
.
.
```

The message is indeed one giant line from the update manager. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Which command did you execute? did you provide the entire output of the command?

Comment: did you review [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/909324/544264)?

Comment: For some reason, you have Ubuntu 16.10's `yakkety` repositories and Debian's `jessie`, `stable`, and `unstable` repositories. You shouldn't include Debian repositories, and you shouldn't have 16.10 repositories. You need to manually repair that.