# Can I upgrade from 16.04 GNOME edition to 17.10 without problems?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, upgrade, 17.10

I am using the [GNOME Distribution of Ubuntu](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-lts-is-here/).

Is it possible to upgrade this system to [Ubuntu 17.10](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/1710) without problems and loss of data?

Comment: Might as well just wait 1 more month and upgrade to 18.04 which is also a LTS and should provide a more pleasant upgrade experience.

Comment: 17.10 (2017.Oct release) is now a very short term idea; it only had a 9 month life at release, now more than half gone.  16.04LTS default upgrade path is to 18.04 which you'll have to do soon even if you go to 17.10; I agree with devius

Comment: i know, but my plan was to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 without losing my data. That is why i wanted to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 -> Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909323/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-ubuntu-17-10-upgrade)

Comment: It's better to wait. LTS releases are much more stable as @devius mentioned above. Also upgrades in general can be unstable

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is possible, but nobody ever will guarantee you a successful Upgrade without knowing your environment. Why not backup your data, do the Upgrade and in case of failure, restore the data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, I just did it two days ago and my system is working fine.